# Javascript doesn't seem to work for html page with html tags inside framesets

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I want to run the following JavaScript on a site with no `<body>` tag and it consists of `<framesets>` to nest documents.

```
document.onclick= function(event) {
    if (event===undefined)
        event= window.event;
    var target = 'target' in event ? event.target : event.srcElement;
    alert("clicked");
};
```

The HTML document I am dealing with is quite bizarre as I've never seen anything like this. Anyhow, the JavaScript will not run but no error message is shown. Firebug returns only the HTML xPath, not the entire/html/frameset/frame/html/body/div/a, so I can see there is some problem with having frameset tags. Note I have no control over the target site I am supposed to test.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>weird site...</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="IE=EmulateIE8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    </head>
    <frameset frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0" cols="*,796,*">
        <frame scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" src="/main/left.php" name="links" style="background-color: transparent;">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <div>
                        <a>text</a>
                    </div>
                    ....
                </body>
            </html>
        </frame>
        <frameset frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0" rows="58,*">
            <frame scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="/main/top.php" name="oben" style="background-color: transparent;">
                <html>
                    <body>....</body>
                </html>
            </frame>
            <frameset frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0" cols="116,680">
                <frame scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="/main/login.php" name="persoenliches" style="background-color: transparent;"></frame>
                <frame scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="/main/index.php" name="mitte" style="background-color: transparent;"></frame>
            </frameset>
        </frameset>
        <frame scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" src="/main/right.php" name="heartbeat"></frame>
        <noframes></noframes>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you putting your Javascript code? Remember that each different frame is an independent page, containing separate `windows` (global variables) and `documents` so you can't write an event handler in one place and expect it to work for everyone.

Comment: I am running the js code in the Console tab of Firebug. Is there a way to access all documents of all frames in one go? is it possible to access a frame by xpath? `/html/frameset/frame/html/body/a`

Comment: I don't think you can use a normal XPath to access iframes like that. After you get to the frame you need to get its document in a separate step before moving on. Also, there is the issue that your JS is only allowed to peek inside a frame if it came from the same domain as the parent frame.